# When downloading bigger (video) file using Spring-boot and java nio package only download part of the file

Tags: java, spring-boot

When downloading bigger (specially videos) files using Spring-boot and  java nio package only download part of the file. But smaller files such as images, pdf ect get downloaded properly and usable.

For example : Let say video size is 3.5MB but when downloaded it only show 160KB and cannot play it in any player(that is because, probably partially downloaded)

## Following is the controller

```
package com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.controllers;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.model.FileDetails;
import com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.services.FileDownloadService;

@RestController
public class FileDownloadController {

    @Autowired
    FileDownloadService fileDownloadService;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/filedownload")
    public String downloadFile(@RequestBody FileDetails fileDetails){

        return fileDownloadService.downloadFile(fileDetails);
    }

}
```

## Following is Service

```
package com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.services;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.exceptions.FileNotDownloadedCorrectlyException;
import com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.model.FileDetails;
import com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.utils.Constants;

@Service
public class FileDownloadService {

    public String downloadFile(FileDetails fileDetails) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileDetails.getFileUrl());
            ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url
                    .openStream());
            String downloadedFile = fileDetails.getFileDownloadLocation() + "/"
                    + fileDetails.getFileName() + "."
                    + fileDetails.getFileType();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    downloadedFile);
            WritableByteChannel writableByteChannel = fileOutputStream
                    .getChannel();
            //
            //
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

            while (readableByteChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
                buffer.flip();
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                    writableByteChannel.write(buffer);

                }
                buffer.clear();
            }
            //
            //
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            return downloadedFile;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new FileNotDownloadedCorrectlyException(
                    Constants.FILE_NOT_DOWNLOADED_CORRECTLY, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileNotDownloadedCorrectlyException(
                    Constants.FILE_NOT_DOWNLOADED_CORRECTLY, e);
        }

    }
}
```

## Following is FileDetails model

```
package com.filedownloader_with_nio_package.model;

public class FileDetails {
 private String fileName;
 private String fileUrl;
 private String fileType;
 private String fileDownloadLocation;
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
public String getFileUrl() {
    return fileUrl;
}
public void setFileUrl(String fileUrl) {
    this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
}
public String getFileType() {
    return fileType;
}
public void setFileType(String fileType) {
    this.fileType = fileType;
}
public String getFileDownloadLocation() {
    return fileDownloadLocation;
}
public void setFileDownloadLocation(String fileDownloadLocation) {
    this.fileDownloadLocation = fileDownloadLocation;
}

}
```

## This is request body

```
{
    "fileName": "SB2",
    "fileUrl": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_gkQK8sAlgTslzfRGOvNtbEAwtoPeyJv",
    "fileType":"mp4",
    "fileDownloadLocation": "C:/DownloadedFiles"
}
```

I went trough the related questions and answers but I could not find a proper solution for this. 
Can any one help to sort out the issue ? or any idea about this welcome.

Comment: Let me guess - chunked body?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Drive API to do this? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

Comment: @StephaneM requirement not only download from  google drive , any link to a file from internet should be able to use.

Answer (score -1):

you need a `URL` with `extension` to download large files (videos) when using NIO packages.

```
   URL url = new URL("https://elpvideo.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/4445/4445.mp4");
```

If your hosting service provides an API to download files with a particular token then NIO packages don't work properly.

```
 URL url = new URL("https://fv2-1.failiem.lv/down.php?i=sk2j3yuya");
```

Tip:

if you are downloading a large size of the file then make sure to set `timeout` if not then it will be disconnected in the middle.

```
  URL url = new URL("https://elpvideo.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/4445/4445.mp4");

 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  urlConnection.setReadTimeout((1000*30)); //30 mins

  ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Nonsense. NIO can't even see the URL. And not using a timeout does not mean it 'will' be disconnected in the middle; and using one will only detect that case another way, not prevent it.